# select multi-digit zeros

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm parsing a file and storing it's name/value pairs in a mysql database.  The zero values have a variety of digits: 0, 00, 0000.  Is there a query to select all of them, without concatenating 'or' statements?

```
SELECT * FROM APP WHERE VALUE = '0' OR VALUE = '00' OR VALUE = '000';
```

Comment: Are those VARCHAR or INT columns?

Comment: SELECT * FROM APP WHERE VALUE > -0.0000000000001 AND VALUE < 0.0000000000001     (if that 0.0000000000001 is closer to 0 then your smallest non 0 value)

Comment: Is a negative sign or decimal point allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using REGEX:

`SELECT * FROM APP WHERE VALUE REGEXP '0+';`

Answer (score 1):

While there are lots of possibilities to select `VARCHAR` 0,00,... (such as `RLIKE` and friends) I recommend you put some extra effort into your import and convert those to `INT` on import

Some selectors:

- `colname RLIKE '0+';`
- `CAST(colname AS UNSIGNED)=0`

Comment: I can't.  Many of the values are character-based.

Comment: What I ment is: Have your value table have a `VARCHAR` col, an `INT` col (maybe more) and a "type" column `ENUM('V','I')`again maybe more. On Import populate the needed col and set the type.

Comment: I see what you mean.  The java library I'm using reads everything in as a string, so I'd have to do the regex either in the application code or the sql query.